# Getting "database is locked" error messages from Trac

Tags: trac

Wondering if anyone has gotten the infamous "database is locked" error from Trac and how you solved it. It is starting to occur more and more often for us. Will we really have to bite the bullet and migrate to a different DB backend, or is there another way?

See these two Trac bug entries for more info:

http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/3446

http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/3503

**Edit 1** Thanks for the answer and the recommendation, which seems to confirm our suspicion that migrating to PostgreSQL seems to be the best option. The SQLite to PostgreSQL script is here: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SqliteToPgScript Here goes nothing...

**Edit 2 (solved)** The migration went pretty smooth and I expect we won't be seeing the locks any more. The speed isn't noticeably better as far as I can tell, but at least the locks are gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a problem with the current SQLite adapter.  There are scripts to migrate to postgres and I can really recommend that, postgres is a lot speeder for trac.

Answer (score 2):

They just fixed this on Sept 10, and the fix will be in 0.11.6.

http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/3446#comment:39

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is 100% fixed just yet. We experience this error a couple dozen times a day. In our case, we have 30+ people updating Trac *constantly* as we use it for tracking pretty much everything, and not just bugs. From ticket #3446:

> Quite obviously, this is [...] due to
>   our database access patterns... which
>   currently limit our concurrency to at
>   most one write access each few seconds

Comment: moving to PostgreSQL solved the problem for us. we have ~15 people using Trac all the time.